# need to use flex based property instead of width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have one div where i have to show background and background till 70% of the page

so for the div i tried

```
.transaction {
    width: calc(100% - 25%);
}
```

my div looks like this

```
<div class="transaction">Code goes here</div>
```

working perfect, but instead of width, i want to have flex calculate that `width` and display it, i want to keep the usage of width to be very very minimum until i cannot do something from `flexbox` and only then i should be able to use the width

Comment: The question is not clear enough to me, what is the result at the moment? What is the desired result?

Comment: btw i want to avoid width in case the any flex property can be used to do this, that is what my question @HaimAbeles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to the children a definition of
`flex-basis: 70%;`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">code goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @noah If this answer answers your question, I would appreciate it if you marked it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

By default the items inside of flex will fit the content. You can set a max-width that is relative to its container width. You don't need a `calc()` when you know the final output unit.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  background: tomato;
  max-width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>This is some content with a max width of 70%</div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks, btw i want to avoid width in case the any flex property can be used to do this, that is what my question

Comment: @Noah, I don't think that is possible. The only property that takes units, is `flex-basis` but that will overwrite the fit-to-content width.